# The command "mv test_file TEST_FILE" fails with "mv: ‘test_file’ and ‘TEST_FILE’ are the same file" in a CIFS filesystem

Tags: linux, cifs, mv

I have a CIFS filesystem mounted in an Oracle Linux 7 server:

```
//win-server/shared-folder on /data1/shared_folder type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=winuser,domain=mydomain.com,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=10.10.10.10,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

I have a file called test_file in /data1/shared_folder. When I try to rename it as TEST_FILE I receive the following error message:

```
$ mv test_file TEST_FILE
mv: ‘test_file’ and ‘TEST_FILE’ are the same file
$ echo $?
1
```

mv -f test_file TEST_FILE has the same result.
I understand that this is related to the Windows server being case insensitive to the file names. But with a previous Red Hat Linux 5 server mounting the same CIFS filesystem, the same command did not show any message, and returned exit code 0. This is the behaviour that I need to replicate in the Oracle Linux 7 server.

I suspect this could be related to the mount.cifs options. I have tried the options cache=none ( suggested in https://superuser.com/questions/1132269/mv-command-reports-x-and-y-are-the-same-file-cifs-filesystem ), cache=loose, and ignorecase, but they did not help.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Update:**
The options that I have indicated in /etc/fstab are:

```
rw,user=...,password=...,domain=...,uid=...,gid=...,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755
```

Comment: I'd expect that ignorecase/nocase is the option that causes the issue. I believe case-sensitivity is the default *if the server supports it*, so I guess that means your server is claiming not to.

Comment: Is that an actual Windows server? Which version of Windows? Why are you forcing the connection to SMBv1?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes it is a windows server 2012 R2. I have not indicated the SMB version, it seems it is the default.

Comment: @jhnc I have tried with ignorecase and without ignorecase. In both cases, the same result.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have just tried mounting the filesystem with vers=3.0, but same result